# How to change value Bulma.io variables with Angular 8

Tags: css, angular, bulma

I'm using `Bulma.io` in an `Angular 8` project and I've install Bulma with this command: `npm install bulma`. After that I've included the styles in my `angular.json` file:

```
"styles": [
   "src/styles.css",
   "node_modules/bulma/css/bulma.css"
   ],
   "stylePreprocessorOptions": {
   "includePaths":
         "node_modules",
          "node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities"
   ]
   },
```

I can work with `Bulma` but I can't override the variables to change, for instance, the background color of a `navbar`. 
Here's my `scss` file that overrides the `background-color` of a `navbar`:

```
@import 'horizontal-navbar.component.css';
@import 'initial-variables';
@import "functions";
@import "bulma";

$navbar-background-color: #fff;
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Having the same issue here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: It says in the docs to set the overrides before importing bulma - https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/variables/

Answer (score 2):

We can import this as we do it with node sass

First save the `bulma` package

`npm install bulma --save`

then go to the `style.scss` and give the below code

```
// Set your brand colors
$purple: #8a4d76;
$pink: #fa7c91;
$brown: #757763;
$beige-light: #d0d1cd;
$beige-lighter: #eff0eb;

// Update Bulma's global variables
$family-sans-serif: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
$grey-dark: $brown;
$grey-light: $beige-light;
$primary: $purple;
$link: $pink;
$widescreen-enabled: false;
$fullhd-enabled: false;

// Update some of Bulma's component variables
// $body-background-color: $beige-lighter;
$body-background-color: #fff;
$control-border-width: 2px;
$input-border-color: transparent;
$input-shadow: none;

// Import only what you need from Bulma
@import '~node_modules/bulma/sass/utilities/_all';
@import '~node_modules/bulma/sass/base/_all';
@import '~node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/button';
@import '~node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/container';
@import '~node_modules/bulma/sass/elements/title';
@import '~node_modules/bulma/sass/form/_all';
@import '~node_modules/bulma/sass/components/navbar';
@import '~node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/hero';
@import '~node_modules/bulma/sass/layout/section';
```

I took this example from https://bulma.io/documentation/customize/with-node-sass/